# complex link with link_to rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, link-to

I want to put in single link_to these options.

`<%= prods.manufacturer.name %> <%= prods.name %>`

So that generated link would be together in single underline. Like Komptech Cribo900, that is one link. But at this moment I have 2 links and clickig on them sends me to manufacturer view or product view. I want to be able to go only to product view.

Product and Manufacturer models have relationship between them.

I tried 

`<%= link_to (prods.manufacturer.name prods.name), prods%>` and
`<%= link_to (prods.manufacturer.name)(prods.name), prods%>` with errors. Is there any way to do this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `String` [interpolation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Interpolation):

```
<%= link_to "#{prods.manufacturer.name} #{prods.name}", prods %>
```

Comment: @EdgarsRozenfelds glad to help. Please accept the answer when you can.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%=link_to "#{prods.manufacturer.name}#{prods.name}", prods%>
```